# weather app form returns "undefined" when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

[![weather app form undefined

GITHUB: https://github.com/mylaconcepts/Weather-Journal-App

When I enter a zip code and how I am feeling into the forms on the webpage it returns undefined in the "Most Recent Entry" position.  I am not sure how to start troubleshooting this error.

```js
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', clickedGenerate);

function clickedGenerate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
    const content = document.getElementById('feelings').value;

    retrieveWeather(baseURL, zip, apiKey)
    .then(function (userData){
        getData('/add',  { date:newDate, temp:userData.main.temp, content})
    }).then(function (newData) {
        updateUI()
    })
```

```html
 </div>
  <div class ="holder zip">
    <label for="zip">Enter Zipcode here</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip" placeholder="enter zip code here">
  </div>
  <div class ="holder feel">
    <label for="feelings">How are you feeling today?</label>
    <textarea class= "myInput" id="feelings" placeholder="Enter your feelings here" rows="9" cols="50"></textarea>
    <button id="generate" type = "button"> Generate </button>
  </div>
  <div class ="holder entry">
    <div class = "title">Most Recent Entry</div>
   <div id = "entryHolder">
    <div id = "date"></div> 
   <div id = "temp"></div>
   <div id = "content"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcKH5.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcKH5.png)

Comment: well the then returns nothing

Comment: Don't forget to return inside your `then` callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

```
retrieveWeather(baseURL, zip, apiKey)
.then(userData => getData('/add',  { date:newDate, temp:userData.main.temp, content}))
.then(newData => updateUI()) 
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

you have to return the values in `.then()` or just use a arrow function to return implicitly.